# Binding within a ListView GroupStyle Header

Tags: wpf, listview

I use a `ListView.GroupStyle` in conjunction with a `HeaderTemplate` to style ListView Headers.

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource headerTemplate}" />
</ListView.GroupStyle>
```

...

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="headerTemplate">
        <Border Opacity=".9" Padding="0,5,0,5" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#ffffff">
            <Grid Margin="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock 
                    Grid.Column="0" 
                    Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Margin="5" Padding="5"     
                    HorizontalAlignment="left" 
                    Content="{Binding ???}" 
                    Command="{Binding ???}" />
                </StackPanel>

            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Now I would like to put controls in that `headerTemplate` - e.g. a Button to execute actions to all entries within that group. How do I do this? How is Binding done within a GroupStyle HeaderTemplate?

Comment: They're done the same as normal... what have you tried and what problems did you face? Take a look at the [`GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupstyle.headertemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: The problem I am facing is that the DataContext for the  GroupStyle HeaderTemplate is `CollectionViewGroup`. I cannot bind my stuff against CollectionViewGroup - I need my own ViewModel to bind against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`RelativeSource Binding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource(v=vs.110).aspx) to access the `DataContext` of the `GridView` from the `HeaderTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="headerTemplate">
    <Border Opacity=".9" Padding="0,5,0,5" ...>
        <Grid Margin="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock 
                Grid.Column="0" 
                Text="{Binding Name}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Margin="5" Padding="5"     
                HorizontalAlignment="left" 
                Content="{Binding DataContext.SomeProperty, RelativeSource={
                    RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type GridView}}}" 
                Command="{Binding DataContext.AnotherProperty, RelativeSource={
                    RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type GridView}}}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```